# Tests in Postman for requests that return random values

Tags: json, rest, postman

I'm learning Postman. I have a query that returns random values from a key:

```
   GET https://apitest.backendless.com/A1DA5DF0-8D22-BAC4-FF56-9A0074DC9B00/8834B7F8-88BD-4472-9051-71BE31A3EE5B/hive/rootKeys/set/root1/random?count=2
```

You can use a working request. The key contains the values `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`

The question is: how do I write tests for a query that returns random values? Here is a test

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    pm.test("Random values", function(){
        pm.expect(jsonData).to.eql(["1", "2"])
})
```

won't do because it might return ["3", "5"]. How then to check the validity of the request?

Comment: Don't waste your time for tests for Postman. Try to learn something that  is really usefull.

Comment: @Serge I need this =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic check could be something like this:

```js
let response = pm.response.json();

pm.test("Random Number Check", () => {
    pm.expect(response, "Response contains a number not in the array").to.contain.oneOf(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]);
});
```

Comment: That was similar to my initial proposal, but then it would pass if the payload returned results out of the scope 1-5 right? I wanted to use any/every but I couldn't find a way to do it validating the 5+ range :)

Comment: Yours would fail if it didn't eql your assertion. Mine looks at the response and checks if the numbers return are one of the numbers in the array. If the numbers returned were outside of that array, it would fail. It's a very basic example given the code you provided 

Comment: Thank you very much! Perhaps you can tell me where I can read more about tests in Postman, apart from the official documentation, I have already read it several times)

Comment: That's not how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a postman request for you to test directly (https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/playground/request/19391207-0bbb11cb-249c-4fe2-963e-5b73b8cabc9b). It sends a payload with a random array with values from 1 to 5. You can click send several times and see the differences. You can open that link and test it. The test itself tries to validate that only values from 1 to 5 exist in the array:

```js
pm.test("Check that array only contains numbers from 1 to 5 ", function () {
    let jsonData = pm.response.json();
    let array = jsonData.data
    array.every( x => x >= 1 && x <=5 )
});
```

This covers scenarios where the data would send a value outside the range you described.